# JSON to Javascript object literal notation?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The methods of the dynamic Google Graph API want Javascript object literals as their argument, but I only have the data as JSON. What do I do? Is there any way that I could convert my JSON to an object literal?

The format they want is here:
http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable

I PHP, and also jQuery front end. I would appreciate front end or back end solutions. In the back end, I actually have the data in associative arrays so I can do anything with it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSON is designed as a *subset* of Javascript object literal notation. Any<sup>*</sup> valid JSON code is already valid to interpret as a JavaScript literal.

<sup><sub>* Technically, a few rare whitespace characters are treated differently, but this is relevant to almost nobody.</sub></sup>

Comment: It was a bug in my code to led me to ask this question, but I am happy I did as now I can feed the API data very easily with PHP's json_encode()! Thx.